# Find list of missing textures / files?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, texturing, node-editor

When Blender can't find an image-based texture in a node-based material, it just replaces that image with purple. Sometimes I accidentally move files on my hard drive, and Blender replaces parts of my render (the missing image-based textures) with purple, which I sometimes don't realize until I've finished a 20 hour render... For example, in After Effects, I can just search for "missing" in the search box and all missing files in that project show up. **Where in Blender (2.8) can I find a list of missing files, like image-based textures (JPG, PNG etc.)?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**File > External Data > Report Missing Files** shows all missing files/textures.
[image]

Comment: I clicked it but nothing happened. Can you show what the expected behavior of this should look like? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If you make *File* > *External Data* > *Find Missing Files* you'll find your files but I don't know how to easily show their location. You could pack them all with *File* > *External Data* > *Pack All Into Blend* then unpack to another folder if necessary: *File* > *External Data* > *Unpack All Into Files*.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you will have to check your nodes and tell Blender the new path, where you moved the file. I don't think Blender has that same option you have in AE.